# SpringBoot+thymeleaf не работает встраивание (вложение) страниц

Tags: bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

addUser.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>CRUDSpringBoot</title>
</head>
 
<body>
 
 
 
<div th:fragment="content">                   //Вместе с th:fragment не хочет работать
    <p>привет я addUser</p>
    <form  method="post" th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/admin/add}" >
 
            <label for="name" > Name </label>
            <input id="name" type="text" th:field="${user.name}"/>
 
            <label for="login"> Login </label>
            <input id="login" type="text" th:field="${user.login}"/>
 
            <label for="password"> Password </label>
            <input id="password" type="text" th:field="${user.password}"/>
 
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

getAllUser.html

```html
<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                       <p>Вторая страница</p>
                        <div th:replace="adduser :: content"></div>
                    </div>
```

**ОШИБКА в консоли**
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
**ОШИБКА в браузере**
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Feb 28 08:24:21 EET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (adduser:17)

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос!
Т.к мы встраиваем одну страницу в другую на нужно передать такие же атрибут и другой странице
Атрибуты adduser.html мы также добавили в getAlluser.html
Эти атрибуты model.addAttribute("user", new User());

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping
public String getAllUser(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("getAllUser", this.userService.getAllUser());
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());                                       //Добавил эту строчку
    return "getAlluser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddPageUser(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "adduser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    userService.addUser(user);
    return "redirect:/admin";
```